# Renting a mobility scooter in Bergamo, Italy

Tags: italy, rental, accessibility

Does anyone know of a way to rent a mobility scooter in Bergamo, Italy?

The answer can be a company that rents them out or a site which will help me to find such a company.

Comment: While this looks like a shopping question, it is a legitimate request for help with finding a help for someone with a handicap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call and ask here, but may they speak only Italian.

EV4B noleggio e vendita Veicoli Elettrici Bergamo
5,0 
Via Pietro Paleocapa, 1/D · 
+39 035 268 1001

Il Caravaggio Orio al Serio International Airport ( That is inside the airport, when you arrive ) 
Sala arrivi, Via Orio al Serio, 13 · 
+39 02 9475 7979